# PhoneGap jquery mobile error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am working on my first phoneGap application and i am facing problems in using jquery mobile with it, i already downloaded the jquery mobile and

i am trying to divide the page to 4 divs every one with a specific color and print an alert when i click on any of them. 
this is my code inside index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />


        <title>Hello World</title>
        <style>
            .camArea
            {
                width: 50%;
                float:left;
                background: red;
                    height: 100%;
            }
            .camSection
            {
                width:100%;
                height: 50%;

            }
            .camContainer
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:fixed;
            }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="camContainer">
            <div class="camSection"> 
                <div class="camArea" style = "background:blue" ></div>
                <div class="camArea" style = "background:#ff4512"></div>
             </div>

            <div class="camSection"> 
                <div class="camArea" style = "background:green"></div>
                <div class="camArea" style = "background:#34d3ff"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();

                $(".camArea").click(function(){
                    alert("Toto")
                });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

when i lunch the app or refresh the page i get this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

and this is what my app looks like with the error

[image]

and whwn i click to see the error i see this

[image]

when i try to check if the $ is existed by writing it on the console i get this

```
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

this is the image 
[image]

and when i try to include the this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

in the `<head></head>`

i get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined`
and here is the image :
[image]
can any one help with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

The error  :

```
$ is not defined
```

is a general message for not including jquery.js file.

It is diffrent form jquery mobile refrences.

So simply insert jquery.js at the header and before jquery mobile refrence file.